# Bluetooth library to get a device location without pairing

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am looking for a way to do a Bluetooth device scan and get all the devices that are discoverable with their distance. If it's possible can I archive it without pairing?

I assume a similar logic is used by iBeacons where it is possible for an app to get a distance from a beacon without pairing to it.

Comment: Please be reminded iBeacon cannot tell the actual distance but can only tell if you are "around" the iBeacon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using linux/Bluez? One thing you can do is to scan for devices with some custom code or an

```
hcitool scan
```

Then you just need to be monitoring with hcidump or something similar, and you can get relative distance locations based on the RSSI value. Here is an example output:

```
hcidump -a
< HCI Command: Inquiry (0x01|0x0001) plen 5
lap 0x9e8b33 len 8 num 0
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
Inquiry (0x01|0x0001) status 0x00 ncmd 1
> HCI Event: Extended Inquiry Result (0x2f) plen 255
bdaddr 11:22:33:44:55:66 mode 1 clkoffset 0x129e class 0x7a020c rssi -89
```

Of course you would probably want to make your scan loop so that you will continuously get the RSSI.